# GCC++ !! undefined reference to

Tags: c++, gcc

**can someone help me with this error**

I try to compile, but I get the error: undefined reference to.

please help me thank you

this is the error

```
./build\transactiontablemodel.o:transactiontablemodel.cpp:(.text+0xbe5): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::labelForAddress(QString const&) const'
./build\transactiontablemodel.o:transactiontablemodel.cpp:(.text+0x1151): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::labelForAddress(QString const&) const'
./build\transactiontablemodel.o:transactiontablemodel.cpp:(.text+0x24f8): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::labelForAddress(QString const&) const'
./build\coincontroldialog.o:coincontroldialog.cpp:(.text+0x4860): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::labelForAddress(QString const&) const'
./build\coincontroldialog.o:coincontroldialog.cpp:(.text+0x5802): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::labelForAddress(QString const&) const'
./build\editaddressdialog.o:editaddressdialog.cpp:(.text+0x672): undefined refer
 to `AddressTableModel::Receive'
./build\editaddressdialog.o:editaddressdialog.cpp:(.text+0x67e): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::Send'
./build\editaddressdialog.o:editaddressdialog.cpp:(.text+0x6a0): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::addRow(QString const&, QString const&, QString const
&, int)'
./build\walletmodel.o:walletmodel.cpp:(.text+0x1bca): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::updateEntry(QString const&, QString const&, bool, int)'
./build\walletmodel.o:walletmodel.cpp:(.text+0x5dad): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::AddressTableModel(CWallet*, WalletModel*)'
./build\messagemodel.o:messagemodel.cpp:(.text$_ZN16MessageTablePriv19refreshMessageTableEv[__ZN16MessageTablePriv19refreshMessageTableEv]+0x584): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::labelForAddress(QString const&) const'
./build\messagemodel.o:messagemodel.cpp:(.text$_ZN16MessageTablePriv19refreshMessageTableEv[__ZN16MessageTablePriv19refreshMessageTableEv]+0x784): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::labelForAddress(QString const&) const'
./build\messagemodel.o:messagemodel.cpp:(.text$_ZN16MessageTablePriv10newMessageERK12SecMsgStored[__ZN16MessageTablePriv10newMessageERK12SecMsgStored]+0x140): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::labelForAddress(QString const&) const'

./build\messagemodel.o:messagemodel.cpp:(.text$_ZN16MessageTablePriv16newOutboxMessageERK12SecMsgStored[__ZN16MessageTablePriv16newOutboxMessageERK12SecMsgStored]+0x140): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::labelForAddress(QString const&) const'
./build\shadowbridge.o:shadowbridge.cpp:(.text+0x1042): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::Send'
./build\shadowbridge.o:shadowbridge.cpp:(.text+0x105c): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::Receive'
./build\shadowbridge.o:shadowbridge.cpp:(.text+0x108d): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::addRow(QString const&, QString const&, QString const&, int)'
./build\shadowbridge.o:shadowbridge.cpp:(.text+0x1247): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::labelForAddress(QString const&) const'
./build\shadowbridge.o:shadowbridge.cpp:(.text+0x12d7): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::lookupAddress(QString const&) const'
./build\shadowbridge.o:shadowbridge.cpp:(.text+0x13df): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::lookupAddress(QString const&) const'
./build\shadowbridge.o:shadowbridge.cpp:(.text+0x2540): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::pubkeyForAddress(QString const&, bool) const'
./build\shadowbridge.o:shadowbridge.cpp:(.text+0x1496a): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::Receive'
./build\shadowbridge.o:shadowbridge.cpp:(.text+0x14982): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::addRow(QString const&, QString const&, QString const&, int)'

./build\shadowbridge.o:shadowbridge.cpp:(.text+0x14a32): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::Receive'
./build\shadowbridge.o:shadowbridge.cpp:(.text+0x14a4a): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::addRow(QString const&, QString const&, QString const&, int)'

./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.text+0x152): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::updateEntry(QString const&, QString const&,bool, int)'
./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.text+0x19d): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::setEncryptionStatus(int)'
./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV17AddressTableModel[__ZTV17AddressTableModel]+0x14): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::~AddressTableModel()'
./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV17AddressTableModel[__ZTV17AddressTableModel]+0x18): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::~AddressTableModel()'
./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV17AddressTableModel[__ZTV17AddressTableModel]+0x38): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::index(int, int, QModelIndex const&) const'
./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV17AddressTableModel[__ZTV17AddressTableModel]+0x44): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::rowCount(QModelIndex const&) const'
./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV17AddressTableModel[__ZTV17AddressTableModel]+0x48): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::columnCount(QModelIndex const&) const'
./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV17AddressTableModel[__ZTV17AddressTableModel]+0x50): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::data(QModelIndex const&, int) const'
./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV17AddressTableModel[__ZTV17AddressTableModel]+0x54): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::setData(QModelIndex const&, QVariant const&, int)'
./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV17AddressTableModel[__ZTV17AddressTableModel]+0x58): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::headerData(int, Qt::Orientation, int) const'
./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV17AddressTableModel[__ZTV17AddressTableModel]+0x88): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::removeRows(int, int, QModelIndex const&)'
./build\moc_addresstablemodel.o:moc_addresstablemodel.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV17AddressTableModel[__ZTV17AddressTableModel]+0xa0): undefined reference to `AddressTableModel::flags(QModelIndex const&) const'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Release:457: recipe for target 'release\shadow.exe' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release\shadow.exe] Error 1
```

**transactiontablemodel.cpp**

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shadowproject/shadow/v1.3.3.6/src/qt/transactiontablemodel.cpp

**transactiontablemodel.h**

```
#ifndef TRANSACTIONTABLEMODEL_H
#define TRANSACTIONTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QStringList>

class CWallet;
class TransactionTablePriv;
class TransactionRecord;
class WalletModel;

/** UI model for the transaction table of a wallet.
 */
class TransactionTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TransactionTableModel(CWallet* wallet, WalletModel *parent = 0);
    ~TransactionTableModel();

    enum ColumnIndex {
        Status = 0,
        Date = 1,
        Type = 2,
        ToAddress = 3,
        Narration = 4,
        Amount = 5
    };

    /** Roles to get specific information from a transaction row.
        These are independent of column.
    */
    enum RoleIndex {
        /** Type of transaction */
        TypeRole = Qt::UserRole,
        /** Date and time this transaction was created */
        DateRole,
        /** Long description (HTML format) */
        LongDescriptionRole,
        /** Address of transaction */
        AddressRole,
        /** Label of address related to transaction */
        LabelRole,
        /** Net amount of transaction */
        AmountRole,
        /** Unique identifier */
        TxIDRole,
        /** Is transaction confirmed? */
        ConfirmedRole,
        /** Formatted amount, without brackets when unconfirmed */
        FormattedAmountRole,
        /** Transaction status (TransactionRecord::Status) */
        StatusRole,
        /** Amount of Confirmations */
        ConfirmationsRole
    };

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;

    int lookupTransaction(const QString &txid) const;
private:
    CWallet* wallet;
    WalletModel *walletModel;
    QStringList columns;
    TransactionTablePriv *priv;

    QString lookupAddress(const std::string &address, bool tooltip) const;
    QVariant addressColor(const TransactionRecord *wtx) const;
    QString formatTxStatus(const TransactionRecord *wtx) const;
    QString formatTxDate(const TransactionRecord *wtx) const;
    QString formatTxToAddress(const TransactionRecord *wtx, bool tooltip) const;
    QString formatTxAmount(const TransactionRecord *wtx, bool showUnconfirmed=true) const;
    QString formatNarration(const TransactionRecord *wtx) const;
    QString formatTooltip(const TransactionRecord *rec) const;
    QString txStatusDecoration(const TransactionRecord *wtx) const;
    QVariant txAddressDecoration(const TransactionRecord *wtx) const;

public slots:
    void updateTransaction(const QString &hash, int status);
    void updateConfirmations();
    void updateDisplayUnit();

    friend class TransactionTablePriv;
};

#endif
```

I compiled it on Windows 7 using Mingw

can someone help me what is the solution of this error. and what is all about this error

Comment: Maybe you are missing some header file? It would help if you included more information on how you are compiling, plus the code that is causing the issue

Comment: Where is your code? How are you compiling it? It's good that you're posting error messages, but without any information about what _produced_ these error messages in the first place, it's hard to say anything relevant.

Comment: As much as I hate that link because it's so broad that an asker's unlikely to find the case that best fits them, you've provided effectively zero information to help us narrow it down for you. In the old days we'd back up our code and then start removing huge swaths of the code until we isolated the source of the problem, experimented with it for a while, and then killed it. The approach still works quite well. In fact it's the basis behind [mre]. Give the link a read and apply the approach it describes. If you are still stuck, update this question or ask a new question based around the MRE.

Comment: i already updated  my question sir